# UserControls not rendering in ascx.cs page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have given    `<%@ Register TagName="sc" TagPrefix="sd" Src="~/controls/smplcart.ascx" %>` but even the User Controls are not rendered in the aspx page.    `<sd:sc ID="contact"  runat="server" />` error says its not a known element .This occurs if there is a compilation error in the website or missing the web.config file. How could I get ridden from this problem, Any help .Thanks in advance.

`<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="header.ascx.cs" Inherits="controls.header" %>
<%@ Register TagName="topmenu" TagPrefix="sd" Src="~/dive/controls/topmenu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagName="langselect" TagPrefix="sd" Src="~/dive/controls/langselect.ascx" %>`

`<div id="<%= headCss %>">
    <div class="header_margins">
        <div class="logo" id="logo" runat="server">
            <a href="home.aspx">
     <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Alt" width="118" height="118" border="0" /></a>
        </div>`
      `<!-- start: Top Menu -->
        <div class="header_top">
            <div class="language_login">
                <sd:topmenu ID="topmenu" runat="server" />
                <sd:langselect ID="langselect" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: Top Menu -->
        <div class="header_bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: If you have `TagPrefix="pd"` and `TagName="sc"` you should reference your control with a tag like `<pd:sc` and not `<sd:sc`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake and I have edited it.

Comment: can you paste the full ascx markup here in your question? it would be a bit easier to understand...

Comment: @DavidePiras I have posted the code.....the intellisense is not getting while entering '<sd:' and the topmenu is underlined and shown the error that I told in the question